# Cast problem with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I'm tring to get my product's types to a list with Linq.

```
var types = (from t in NHibernateSession.Linq<Product>()
             select t.ProductType).Distinct().ToList<ProductType>();         
return types;
```

But its giving an Unable to cast object of type error

'...Domain.Product' to type '...Domain.ProductType'.

ProductType is a property of Product.

```
<many-to-one name="ProductType" class="Portal.Domain.ProductType, TilePortal.Domain" column="ProductTypeID" not-null="true" ></many-to-one>
```

Edit: It seems like Linq to Nhibernate is not mature enough to handle such queries. I simply want to be able to create a simple SQL query that fetch distinct ProductType's from DB without bringing all products which is no-go for a production db that has millions of products. So if you can illustrate how to do this using HQL os Criteria API that will also do..

Comment: What's the relationship between product and type?

Comment: is it on the var types line?  or the return types line?

Comment: Since you are selecting the `Type` property, and assuming `Product.Type` returns an object of type `Type`, you shouldn't need the `.ToList<Type>()` at all. Can you show us the `Product` object and explain its relationship to `Type`?

Comment: @yigit, See my updated answer. There is no need to query products when you want product types.

Answer (score 2):

You might be running into an issue with the nHibernate LINQ implementation.   Do you get the same error with:

```
 var types = (from t in NHibernateSession.Linq<Product>()
              select t.Type);
```

If not, what happens when you try using the non-generic `ToList()`?

```
 var types = (from t in NHibernateSession.Linq<Product>()
              select t.Type).Distinct().ToList();
```

As an aside, I'd generally avoid creating a class with a name that conflicts with something in the .NET framework, especially such a basic one as Type.  It can only lead to confusion.  Perhaps you should rename it ProductType.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the linq 2 nh implementation doesn't support this kind of thing yet. You will probably have to execute the sql first and then select the type reference. Like this:

```
var types = (from t in NHibernateSession.Linq<Product>()
         select t).ToList().Select(t => t.Type).Distinct().ToList<Type>();         
return types;
```

If you are not using the latest version of the provider, please update and try your example again. If it's implemented it should work fine.

**Update**

If the only thing you want to do is get all product types. Why not just write this simple query?

```
var types = (from t in NHibernateSession.Linq<ProductType>()
         select t).ToList();
```

There is no need to query your products when you need the types.

Comment: I've executed similar queries using the LINQ-to-NHibernate extension without issue before. It's not an especially complex query.

Comment: this is not what he's after. You cant fetch millions of products from DB then do a distinct on their Type property. Distinct needs to be applied to the initial SQL statement. (And I would also like to know how that is done on nhibernate - maybe using joins?)

Comment: @kaivalya, Of course this isn't a good query and should never be user in production. But as I don't think this kind of query is supported in the linq provider for nhibernate (maybe it is in a later version) this is the only way of writing this exact query with linq 2 nh.

Comment: It's even easier: 

var types = NHibernateSession.Linq<ProductType>().ToList();